# Auto Click do mouse em um conteudo dentro de uma div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, div, script

Gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer uma div com auto click.

Seria assim a pagina carrega e quando alguem clicar em qualquer parte que seja da pagina o mouse vai clica no conteúdo que tiver dentro da div.

no caso eu coloquei um iframe de uma pagina externa. mas poderia ser uma imagem ou um video.

se possivel fazer isso com java script. e que uma vez que o click tenha acontecido a mesma pessoa não possa clicar novamente por 1 dia. ou um intervalo de tempo.

```
 <div id='conteudo'>  
 <iframe frameborder='0' height='260' name='iframe1' scrolling='no' src='url' width='336/>   
</div>
```

Comment: $("#conteudo").click(function(){/*faz alguma coisa*/});

Comment: Explica melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Dessa maneira não irá funcionar, pois você estará clicando de fato no elemento dentro do iframe. Utilizando o jquery pode ser utilizado o método contents dentro do iframe

Ficaria assim:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
var iframeContents = $('iframe').contents()[0];
$(iframeContents).find('seletor').click(function () {
// Aqui entra o seu evento!
});
```

Comment: Me mostra um exemplo do funcionamento. se possivel

Comment: O exemplo tá em cima. O click em sí pode ser no elemento body se preferir. Aí ficaria assim: var iframeContents = $('iframe').contents()[0]; $(iframeContents).find('body').click(function () { alert('click no body'); })

Comment: Não to conseguindo fazer funciona. me mostra ele funcionando com algum iframe

Answer (score 0):

Contanto que você tenha algum evento atrelado ao *click* nesta sua área (que vou chamar de `#meu_elemento`), você pode fazer algo desse tipo:

```
$('#meu_elemento').trigger('click');
```

Você pode deixar o evento como o *default* do elemento, ou fazer um *bind* por conta, como

```
$('#meu_elemento').on('click', function(e){
    $('.target').append('você clicou em #meu_elemento');
});
```

Veja o exemplo em funcionamento:

```js
$('#meu_elemento').on('click', function(e){
    $('.target').append('você clicou em #meu_elemento');
});


setTimeout((function() {
    $('#meu_elemento').trigger('click');
}), 5000);
```

```css
#meu_elemento{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="meu_elemento"></div>

<div class="target"></div>
```

Veja que eu coloquei um `setTimeout()` no `trigger()` pra que você veja ele em ação (note que, se você clicar no quadrado vermelho, o evento se repete). O que ele faz é um simples `append()` de um texto. A partir daí, você pode tratar o seu evento de *click* como achar melhor.

Comment: Por exemplo : esse iframe . como eu daria um click no play nele com esse codigo que vc  fez? <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OuZQNgvNw6s?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: @user3192159 o seu objetivo é dar o play no video automaticamente?

Comment: Eu adicionei um iframe na <div id="meu_elemento"> video iframe yotube </div> mas apos os 5 segundos aparece uma mensagem " você clicou em #meu_elemento" mas o click no video que está dentro da div não acontece.

Comment: A sua pergunta foi sobre click automático dentro de uma div, que foi no que eu baseei a minha resposta. No meu comentário, lhe perguntei se o seu objetivo é *dar o play no vídeo automaticamente*. Se sim, as coisas mudam de figura... Portanto, é este o seu objetivo?

Comment: O video é um exemplo do elemento que estaria na div. poderia ser um link, um pop up, uma imagem.

Comment: Bom, genericamente fica um pouco mais complicado. *iframes* são complicados. No caso específico de videos embedados do youtube, o autoplay depende de um parametro do *src*. Tem uma discussão bacana sobre isso no SO gringo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246939/start-play-embedded-iframe-youtube-video-on-click-of-an-image Mas no caso de outros elementos, a solução é essa mesmo. Lembre-se que o click vai acontecer no elemento que vc setar, e não nos filhos dele

Comment: E se fosse um link ? <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuZQNgvNw6s"></a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element

Comment: aqueles Pop up que abrem automaticamente quando entramos em um site e clicamos em algum link. como funciona? não seria a mesma coisa.

Comment: acho que aí o escopo da sua pergunta muda completamente. pop ups podem ser feitos de várias maneiras

Comment: Eu não quero uma pop up, o que estou tentando fazer é que qualquer objeto que esteja na div especifica seja auto clicavel.

Comment: O codigo que vc fez faz parte do objetivo. ele só não clica no conteudo que esta no iframe

Comment: Provavelmente ele não clica porque não está no mesmo domínio. Para que possa manipular o iframe ele precisa está no mesmo domínio que o seu site. Se não, imagine fazer um iframe do Facebook e então fazer `$('postagem').val('Acesse o site xxx.xxx'); $('submit').click();`. Todo mundo que entrasse no site (e estivesse conectado no facebook) iria carregar o iframe e iria postar um conteúdo no facebook. Imagina isso num site de banco... Enfim. Se seu site é abc.com não pode manipular iframe de outro site sem ser o abc.com. ;)