# Conteudo Auto Clicável com Script

Tags: javascript, script

Pessoal estou tentando usar um script para tentar dar um Play automatico em um video do Youtube.

O mais proximo que encontrei foi o script abaixo.

Esse script faz algo próximo do que preciso, mas ele apenas faz isso em algum link.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">

  window.setTimeout("autoClick()", 5000); // 5 seconds delay

  function autoClick() {
  var linkPage = document.getElementById('ads-container').href;
  window.location.href = linkPage;
   }
  </script>  


 <a href="" id="ads-container"> Dynamic Link </a>
```

O que gostaria de fazer é ao inves desse script dar um auto click em um link.

ele desse um auto click em um conteudo que estivesse dentro de uma div ou Iframe  como esse.

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YBHQbu5rbdQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alguem tem alguma idéia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Só o autoplay normal do youtube já não serve? http://www.youtube.com/embed/LxLLgo4HVp8?autoplay=1

Comment: Na verdade não, o iframe é um exemplo do que seria o conteudo que seria clicavel

Answer (score 4):

Isso não vai ser possivel. Para além de que é enganar o propósito do click (que deixa de ser humano, para ser programado), se a iFrame estiver noutro domínio não é possivel aceder ao DOM dela e consequentemente clicar ou disparar eventos nesse DOM.

Comment: Hum... mas o script acima não faz exatamente isso? só que em um link? a cada 5 segundos ele clica no  link.

Comment: @Endou o script que tens redireciona a página onde fôr corrido para o que estiver na variável `linkPage`. O que procuras "dar um Play automatico em um video do Youtube" não é posivel visto o video estar numa iFrame, [dá erro](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/u27tjd47/) -> `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement'`

Comment: Olha essa pergunta que fiz a algum tempo,  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66673/auto-click-do-mouse-em-um-conteudo-dentro-de-uma-div   seria algo desse tipo

Comment: @Sergio pode me ajudar a ajudar esse usuário nessa pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102884/sistema-em-joomla?noredirect=1#comment210416_102884