# Sistema em Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Não sei se esse é o lugar certo para esta pergunta, mas se não for comentem que eu apago.

Tenho um sistema feito em php normal, 100% feito a mão.
Estou pensando em migrar esse sistema e fazê-lo totalmente em Joomla. Não se detendo as funções necessárias, mas no geral, é recomendado fazer sistemas complexos em Joomla? O que vocês acham?
Técnicamente é possível desenvolver um sistema razoavelmente complexo em Joomla?

Novamente desculpem se aqui não for lugar para esse tipo de pergunta, nesse caso apenas me alertem que eu apago.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta se encaixa como *principalmente baseada em opiniões*

Comment: vou editar @jbueno

Comment: @jbueno o que agente faz nesse caso?

Comment: @jbueno olha o comentário dele: Entendo e concordo. Onde então posso fazer essa pergunta, para ter discussão e ouvir opiniões? Por favor, responda a esse comentário e delete sua resposta para que eu possa deletar a pergunta,

Comment: Existe algum problema na minha resposta, @EduardoSeixas ?

Comment: @TiagoP.C Você pode usar o [chat] para pedir opiniões

Comment: Não Tiago, nenhum problema.

Comment: Criei um chat @EduardoSeixas, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32745/sistema-em-joomla aqui está

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criar um sistema completo em Joomla é uma tarefa de programação sim, então é coerente com a proposta do site.

Fazer um sistema complexo no Joomla vai depender da sua habilidade.
Se você for um intermediário à avançado, você pode até fazer, utilizando-se de plugins prontos, ou desenvolvendo os seus próprios. 
Olha, se você tem seu sistema pronto, qual a necessidade de refaze-lo utilizando Joomla? Você terá que se preocupar com a arquitetura do Joomla, o ciclo de vida de um componente Joomla é muito complicado, então, se fosse para te aconselhar, deixaria o Joomla de lado e continuava com seu sistema.

Comment: A minha ideia de criar um novo sistema em Joomla é o seguinte: Tenho bastante alterações pra fazer no sistema, o que me levaria algum tempo, penso eu que se fosse, ao invés de fazer as alterações manualmente, usasse plugins do Joomla para isso, isso pouparia muito tempo. Estou errado?

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta acaba sendo fechada thiago. Não gaste esforço escrevendo aqui.  A proposta do site é responder à perguntas diretas. A resposta para sua pergunta nada mais é que opiniões. Se 100 respostas forem postadas, pode ocorrer de nenhuma responder à sua pergunta. Se quiser agente conversa no chat.

Comment: Tiago, entende o quanto é complicado. Minha Resposta seria: FUJA DE PLUGINS, DO JOOMLA.  Faça você, suas classes, variáveis, funções. Tenha seu sistema sobre controle. Se Você precisar fazer uma alteração no layout, nos recursos do sistema, você pode se atrapalhar. O Cliente sempre pede algo difícil, então você precisa ter controle sobre seu sistema.

Comment: Outra pessoa pode te responder que uso do Joomla permite que você ganhe tempo sim, utilizando de plugins completos e seguros. Então esse tipo de discussão não é o foco do site. Entende?

Comment: Entendo e concordo. Onde então posso fazer essa pergunta, para ter discussão e ouvir opiniões? Por favor, responda a esse comentário e delete sua resposta para que eu possa deletar a pergunta,

Answer (score 1):

Depende de qual tipo do seu sistema.
 O joomla, nativamente, é ótimo para gerenciar conteúdo e tem um infinidades de plugins que serviriam para deixar o sistema bem completo, entretanto, se O seu sistema não for tão voltado para o usuário realizar edição do conteúdo, te indicaria reescrever seu codigo em um framework de desenvolvimento que hoje em dia existem varias opções excelentes para você escolher.

Segue um link lista vários frameworks php com suas vantagens:
[COMPARATIVO FRAMEWORKS](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/as-melhores-plataformas-php-para-2015/?trace=1519021197&source=single)