# Iframe de site externo

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Tenho uma pagina com `iframe` de site externo, como posso fazer para conseguir clicar automaticamente ao carregar o `iframe` em um botão que tiver determinado `texto` no site externo?

Não exatamente `classe`, `id` ou `name`, mas pelo texto que aparece no botão mesmo, tipo procurar dentro do `iframe` uma determinada palavra e ter uma ação de clique acima do texto.

A questão é como fazer isso, existe outra forma de carregar o site da mesma forma como o `iframe` faz de forma que dentro da minha pagina eu possa interagir com o site externo?

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Acho que esta pergunta é duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102744/129

Answer (score 2):

Você pode acessar o `iframe` por Id (melhor) ou usar `$('iframe')[0]contents()`, sendo que o [0] é índice. Se houver mais de um `iframe`, você terá de setar outro valor.

Pra acessar um input por valor faça assim:

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('input[type="button"][value="Valor desejado"]');
```

Dai é só usar o elemento.

Comment: Obrigada Ricardo `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement` é a mensagem que aparece para iframe com site externo

Comment: Entendi. Quando você diz site externo você quer dizer fora do domínio é isso (por exemplo o site xxx.com.br abre o iframe do yyy.com.br)? Se for, por razões de segurança você não consegue mesmo manipular e conteúdo, apenas do mesmo domínio ou sub-domínio.

Answer (score 0):

acredito que você possa usar um plugin de Text Highlighter para encontrar a palavra, e após isso adicionar um evento de click.

Aqui tem um site com a lista de plugins que podem lhe auxiliar na tarefa. 
[Site com a lista de plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/)

Fiz um teste com o [MARK.JS](https://markjs.io/) e consegui realizar adicionar o click as palavras que são encontradas.

mas não fiz o teste utilizando o Iframe, mas acredito que com isso você já tenha uma ideia.

Veja o resultado no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpav6tL1/254/)

```
 $('mark').on('click', function(){
        alert('teste');
    } );
```

OBS: o código é do próprio site do mark.js, apenas adicionei as linhas de código acima para adicionar o evento as palavras encontradas.

Comment: Obrigada Abner, não esta funcionando o alerta para mim no exemplo que enviou, nem mesmo o exemplo original do codigo que vc indicou. Mas deu pra ter uma ideia pra fazer alguns testes com esses plugins

Comment: Serio ? pior que aqui deu certinho, mais basicamente para você entender, ao procurar uma palavra ele cria um tag mark , usando esse seletor você pode atribuir o evento de click. espero que ajude !

Comment: No entanto, é como  o Ricardo Pontual comentou, você não pode manipular sites que não estejam em seu domino, e caso você esteja utilizando um subdomínio e tenha acesso ao arquivos,  recomendo o uso do velho ajax + div , ou seja, carregar a página html dentro de uma div.